# O que há de errado com esse array de ponteiros em C? (incompatibilidade?)

Tags: c, array, funções, ponteiro, estrutura-de-dados

Olá, recentemente eu estava fazendo um teste até relativamente simples para tentar unificar alguns conceitos que venho estudando, e que verão a seguir. Trata-se de um array de ponteiros que usei como parâmetro de uma função para somar os valores deste após pegá-los na função main. Veja:

```
   #include <stdio.h>


void sum_all(int *pi[7]){
int i=0, sum;
    while(i  < 7){
      sum = *pi[i];
      printf("%d", sum);
      i+=1;
           }

    }



void main (){
   int vector[7] = {3,7,2,5,6,8,1};
   sum_all( &vector[7]);

}
```

estou recebendo o segunte erro na linha 16: "Warning: passing argument 1 of "sum_all" makes pointer from integer without a cast"

```
 sum_all( &vector[7]);
```

Aparentemente estou fazendo algo errado em relação ao parâmetro mas não sei o que ao certo, apesar da teoria que me ocorreu ser de que eu esteja violando alguma regrinha de passagem de parâmetro. quem puder me ajudar ficaria grato.

Atualização: Após a resolução do problema, o código ficou assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void sum_all(int *pi){
int i=0, sum=0;
   while(i  != 6){
    sum += pi[i];

    i+=1;
            }
printf("%d",sum );
    }



void main (){
   int vector[7] = {3,7,2,5,6,8,1};
   sum_all(vector);

}
```

Obrigado aos envolvidos.

Comment: Boa noite, não há necessidade de se utilizar & para passar um array para uma função.

Comment: Quando você passa como parâmetro: &vector[7]` está passando o endereço do oitavo elemento do array mas lembre-se que se você declarou um array com 7 elementos e portanto os índices irão variar de 0 a 6. Para o que deseja use: `void sum_all(int *pi){` e invoque com: `sum_all(vector);`.

Comment: Obrigado, as dicas de vocês ajudaram bastante e o programa funcionou, entretanto fica aqui a curiosidade: no parâmetro da função "sum_all" porque exatamente ele n me permite usar os colchetes? eu li em algum lugar que ele interpreta isso como ponteiro de um ponteiro mas não ficou claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está acontecendo no seu código é que você declara vector como uma matriz de int (int*) e sua função sum_all() espera receber uma matriz de matriz de int (int**), são tipos de dados diferentes.

Outro ponto é que quando uma matriz é usada em uma expressão ou declarada como um parâmetro de função ela decai em um ponteiro que aponta para o primeiro elemento e a informação de quantos elementos ela possui é perdida.

Isso significa que: `void sum_all(int *pi[7])` será convertido para: `void sum_all(int **pi)`.

Para a sua função sum_all() saber quantos elementos tem uma matriz seria necessário passar essa informação através de outro parâmetro.

Eu fiz um exemplo em que a função sum_all() espera receber uma matriz de int no primeiro parâmetro e o comprimento da matriz no segundo parâmetro e retorna a soma dos elementos da matriz para o chamador.

Não é necessário usar o operador **&** para passar uma matriz como argumento ou acessar os elementos da matriz porque o nome da matriz já é um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum_all(int *array, int length) {
  int accumulator = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    accumulator += array[i];
  }

  return accumulator;
}

int main() {
  int vector[] = { 3, 7, 2, 5, 6, 8, 1 };

  int length = (sizeof(vector) / sizeof(vector[0]));

  int sum = sum_all(vector, length);

  printf("%d\n", sum);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: O que exatamente a linha: " int length = (sizeof(vector) / sizeof(vector[0]));" faz?

Comment: @VictorMariano essa linha calcula o comprimento da matriz automaticamente dividindo o tamanho total da matriz que seria o sizeof(vector) pelo tamanho do tipo da matriz que seria o sizeof(vector[0]). Com isso você pode adicionar ou remover elementos da matriz sem se preocupar em calcular manualmente o número de elementos da matriz.